# What is the fastest way to search for a record in a large Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, search, full-text-search

I have to search for a string in data coming from the backend. The data will probably have like 90K records. There will be a search input field which is used to search for the record. Using regular for loop for the entire data doesn't seem ideal and seems very slow. What is the best way to do this? Any specific algorithm I should use?

Comment: Depends on what you're searching for, but it also seems like the back end should be doing more work. If you're searching for data in object values I don't know what else you could do besides iterate.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's a list of databases and we have to select one from that list. But, the list is huge, that's my issue. Running the list through a for loop doesn't make sense. Any help would be great.

Comment: I wonder if compared to the time it will take to load 90k records from an API, the time it will take to iterate them will actually seem that bad. Or in the inverse, I wonder if you may solve this problem only to discover that loading 90k records from the API is unacceptably slow and the searching needs to be done on the backend anyway

Comment: Yup, that: the bulk of time will be on the wire and GC.